# Calling an SQL stored procedure from a script in a different directory

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from an sql script. The only issue is the stored procedure is located in a different folder. Is there a way to call the stored procedure from a different directory (or a way to change directories)?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm using an Oracle database, but the scripts and stored procedures are contained in GitHub. Im using Jenkins to call the script on the database, and I want the script to be able to access the stored procedure (located on folder up and one file down

Comment: I don't know if you are actually trying to execute a stored procedure, which would require that the stored procedure exist in the database in a valid state, or to call a separate script that contains a `create` statement that creates the procedure.  Or something else.  I assume `sql script` means a `SQL*Plus` script.  `SQL*Plus` allows you to call one `SQL*Plus` script using the `@` command and you can provide a relative path, i.e. `@..\another_directory\create_proc.sql`.

Comment: @Justin I'm trying to execute the stored procedure. I will try out the @ command. Thank you!

Comment: You can't execute a stored procedure that is in a file.  That doesn't make sense.  You can execute a stored procedure that has been created in the database.  You can run a `SQL*Plus` script on the file system that creates a procedure.  Or that executes a procedure that exists in the database.